# How can make an autoincrement field in django model which is incrementing not globally but according to another column?

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to create Django model for logging tasks from Celery.

To display this log I assume a need to know the order of the log messages, therefore I should probably have these columns:

```
Some PK
Celery task ID
order of the message
the message
```

Is is somehow possible to make the field "order" autoincrement, but so it autoincrements only in the "celery task ID" independently..?

I mean.. I will run script with ID 42 and log messages

```
taks_id: 42, order: 0, message: "just started"
taks_id: 42, order: 1, message: "running"
taks_id: 42, order: 2, message: "finished"
```

but I can have many task_ids in the database.. and I do not want to fill in always the order of the message

Thanks

Comment: There is a `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` in django. But I don't get the `it autoincrements only in the "celery task ID" independently`

Comment: Please post your model